# MapReduce to insert items into a new collection, in random order

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've got some documents that look like:

```
{
  _id: 3, 
  key: 3, 
  stuff: "Some data"
}
```

Some documents also have a `signUpDate`

We can populate a collection for demo purposes like this:

```
for(i=1; i<=100000; i++){
if(i%3===0)
     db.numbers.insert({_id:i, key:i, stuff:"Some data", signUpDate: new Date()});
else
     db.numbers.insert({_id:i, key:i, stuff:"Some data"});
}
```

... so a third of the documents have a signUpDate

What I'm trying to do is create a map reduce function that takes all the documents, where signUpDate is not null, and insert them into a separate collection, **ordered randomly**

Is this possible?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "ordered randomly"?  do you mean you want $natural order not to correspond to id order?    Also, how big is your collection in real life?

Comment: i mean... not inserted 1,2,3,4,5 etc... (as you can see, the id of documents are incrementing ints)
Data set is around 1 - 2 million documents in 'real life'

Comment: Technically mongodb does not insert in sequential order so the documents are already partly randomised. However to insert then randomly (even distribution) within a collection; then one way would be to write 2m rows in the target collection with an incremental id or a rand() between 0 and 1 and then use rand() to update that row in the target collection with the row from the source, however, your probably just looking to pick them random than store than in random natural order since picking them out again will not nessecarily be as random as natural order

Comment: @Sammaye - did you look at the example code? It inserts an incremental id (within a for loop) as the _id

Comment: can you explain the use case for having them in random order?  maybe there is a different way to guarantee what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I gotta admit my eyes actually looked at the bold text instead of the example code but I guess that's where my eyes were drawn to in your question. However 90% of my comment still applies and I am unsure how that revelation changes things massively. I mean you are looking to insert in random natural order, since it won't with that sample code you would have to pre-alloc the collection and then upsert on random `i`s. as I said that is one way.

Comment: I put an answer on that seems to solve the problem... let me know what you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a solution that works:

Using mongoshell:

First, we populate our data:

```
for(i=1; i<=100000; i++){
if(i%3===0)
     db.numbers.insert({_id:i, key:i, stuff:"Some data", signUpDate: new Date()});
else
     db.numbers.insert({_id:i, key:i, stuff:"Some data"});
}
```

So now, we have a third of our data with a signUpDate.

Now, a super-simple mapreduce:

```
m = function() {emit(this._id, Math.random());}
r = function(key, values){}

db.numbers.mapReduce(m,r, {out: "randomlyOrdered", query: { signUpDate: { $ne : null } }});
```

Next, ensureIndex to speed up sorting:

```
db.randomlyOrdered.ensureIndex({"value":1});
```

Now, find the numbers (randomly sorted)

```
db.randomlyOrdered.find({}, {"_id":1}).sort({"value":1});
```

Comment: but the data in `stuff` will not be written also that will still insert in roughly sequence, fair enough not true sequence due to absence of a sort in the input query to the mr but still it won't be totally "random"

Comment: Yes, but we can query it back out of the collection (randomlyOrdered) using the last query - not quite exactly what i wanted, but as good as it'll get i think

Comment: Ok yea, so long as you use that other collection as a lookup on the rand() is should work good, I just thought...I know it sounds stupid, but why didn't you put rand() on the original collection? I mean you are basically looking for random now instead of inserting in true random.

Comment: Long story... but basically, this mapReduce will run aprox 6 times an hour, to "randomize" the collection again... it's hard to explain lol